# Superimpose PlotLegends, Correctly

Tags: plotting

My aim is to plot each function with distinct **style** superimpose with **color** based upon parameter.

For instance, I have 3 functions of 1 variable and 1 parameter. **Table** command is used for iterating over parameter space & also for colouring the associated curve obtained from the **Plot** command. All 3 functions are plotted with 3 distinct plot style.

After scanning all...or may be I missed something in the search, but I'm not able to correct the **PlotLegends** misfit style both in **Plot** & **ListPlot** commands.

```
{k1, k2, dk} = {0.01, 0.09, 0.01};

f1[x_] = Sin[k x];
f2[x_] = Cos[k x];
f3[x_] = Sin[k x]*Cos[k x];

Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Style[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][(k - k1)/(k2 - k1)]], {k, k1, k2, 
    dk}]], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {"", Dashing[0.03, 0.01], Dashing[0.004]},
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[{"Amp1", "Amp2", "Amp3"}, {Right, Bottom}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improper syntax on dashing.  Use this:

```
PlotStyle -> {"", Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}], Dashing[0.004]}
```

or better, to my taste

```
PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}], Dashing[0.004]}
```

e.g.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Style[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][(k - k1)/(k2 - k1)]],
   {k, k1, k2, dk}]], {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashing[{0.03, 0.01}],
   Dashing[0.004]}, PlotLegends ->
  {Placed[{"Amp1", "Amp2", "Amp3"}, {Right, Bottom}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm amending my default settings also to get the corrections you just suggested...but thanks for the relook.